# How to transform a set of xarray dataset variables into a single variable with additional dimension

Tags: python, dataset, python-xarray, dimensions

I have the below xarray Dataset. Now, I'd like to combine Fender_1, Fender_2, and Fender_3 variables into a single variable called "data" with the dimension "fender_name". Such that I can simply call the variable "data" and select which fender I want using data.sel(fender_name = ...)

How can I achieve this?

[image: xarray dataset]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use [`Dataset.to_array`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_array.html?highlight=to_array#xarray-dataset-to-array):

```
data = ds[["Fender_1", "Fender_2", "Fender_3"]].to_array(dim="fender_name")
```